# Excel - Multiple selection drop down list - no duplication of selection

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I have developed on my excel spreadsheet that multiple items can be selected in a drop down list using the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then

Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
    If oldVal = "" Then

      Else
      If newVal = "" Then

      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal

      End If
    End If
End If


exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

But, I want to now validate the answers that the drop down list items can only be selected once. And preferably, if the user selects that item again, that is it then removed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const SEP As String = ", "
    Dim rngDV As Range
    Dim oldVal As String
    Dim newVal As String
    Dim arr, m, v
    If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngDV = Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation)
    On Error GoTo exitHandler
    If rngDV Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    newVal = Target.Value
    If Len(newVal) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'user has cleared the cell...
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value
    
    If oldVal <> "" Then
        arr = Split(oldVal, SEP)
        m = Application.Match(newVal, arr, 0)
        If IsError(m) Then
            newVal = oldVal & SEP & newVal
        Else
            arr(m - 1) = ""
            newVal = ""
            For Each v In arr
                If Len(v) > 0 Then newVal = newVal & IIf(Len(newVal) > 0, SEP, "") & v
            Next v
        End If
        Target.Value = newVal
    Else
        Target.Value = newVal 'EDIT
    End If

exitHandler:
      Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Lord45 - if you need to restrict this to Column X you can add `If Target.Column <>24 Then Exit Sub` right before `newVal = Target.Value`

Comment: When the cell is empty, and I make a selection, nothing gets entered into the cell. Or if I remove cell contents, same thing...

Comment: Sorry - seems there was a bug there...  Edited to fix.